# Removing duplicates in account tables and update associated records

Tags: mysql

I have table `accounts` from which i want to remove duplicates based on e-mail address, every record in table `account` has a booking in table `booking`, so before i remove duplicates from table `account` i have to associate the booking records to the remaining account. The highest account_id from table `account` will be used to update table `booking` all other will be deletet.

The duplicates table is like this:

[image: This is the table accounts]

The booking table is like this

[image: This is the table: booking]

The table booking should be like this after update

[image: Table booking after update]

how can i do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you @scaisEdge but i have solved in ohter way, 
i have added temporary email field to table booking, 
i have updated the email with account_id join
i have updated the account_id in table booking using email address
finally i have removed the duplicates in table accounts using : NOT IN(select...)